# PCA: removing dominant vector "directions" (isotropy)

Tags: pca, natural-language, linear-algebra, word-embeddings

I am currently reading an [NLP paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HkuGJ3kCb) on improving the representation of word vectors in space. The authors show that embedded words are not uniformly distributed in space but are contained in a lower-dimensional subspace. They propose fixing this problem as follows (cf. page 4, algorithm 1):

1. Compute the PCA change-of-basis matrix $U$ (size $k \times m$) for the original $n \times m$ matrix $V$ (where $k$ is the reduced dimension and $m$ is the original dimension).
2. Compute $(V - \mu) - VU^TU$. The result is an $n \times m$ matrix (original size).

PCA wasn't applied for dimensionality reduction but to remove dominant directions. Refer also to the [code](https://gist.github.com/lgalke/febaaa1313d9c11f3bc8240defed8390) (only a few lines).

My questions:

1. $VU^T$ performs a change of basis (correct?). Multiplying by $U$ restores the matrix to its original size. What happens here geometrically/from a linear algebra perspective? It is no longer the original matrix $V$.
2. Is this a procedure that occurs also in other domains?